# Как создать проект в IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 Ultimate Edition

Tags: java

Всегда хотел начать учить java и о чудо, это наступило. Скачал IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 Ultimate Edition ( выбор пал из-за того, что мне приходилось в ней писать код ) и сразу нашел урок 'Hello Word'. И оказалось, что во всех уроках не такая версия ide. По этому прошу объяснить, как создать проект в моей версии IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 Ultimate Edition.
[alt text http://s020.radikal.ru/i718/1405/c2/e7eaeee4f886.png](http://s020.radikal.ru/i718/1405/c2/e7eaeee4f886.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File-NewProject-Java-JavaEE или File-NewProject-CommandLineApp

А вообще вот

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: @nba-world: Спасибо Большое!